# Firebase DB: how to resolve a Promise and keep listening to Firebase DB changes

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've got 2 functions as following, we 1 does some logic and the other reading a Firebase DB, and continues to listen to changes via using the .on() method.

```
  readDB(path): Promise<any>  {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      firebase.database().ref(path).on('value', (snapshot) => {
      return resolve(snapshot);
        });
      });
    }

NgOnInit() {
  this.readDB(path).then((snap) => {
    this.viewVariable = snap.val().
  });
}
manipulationMethod(newData, path) {
  firebase.database().ref(path).update(newData);
}
```

The goal is to read and listen to Firebase DB changes and in real-time update the Interface when new data is written via the 2nd method.

PROBLEM: when I return a resolved promise, .on() listening is killed and it no longer listens to DB changes. I must use Promises (as I have a lot of async functions).

QUESTION: is there a way to resolve a promise and keep the listening functionality? Like, return a "subscription" or something alike?

Comment: What do you mean by "update the Interface"? Do you mean a web (or Android or iOS) Graphical user Interface connected to the database.

Comment: How do you know that "listening is killed"?  The code you're showing doesn't do anything with the 'value' updates other than repeatedly resolve the same promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promises by definition resolve only once. This when you want to return a promise with data from Firebase, you'll use `once()` instead of `on()`.

If you on the other hand want to return a stream of values, you'll use `on` and return a stream oriented data type. The typical type for this these days is an RxJS `Observable`. For a single example of turning an `on()` into an observable, see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/deltaepsilon/b9ac6bdb5d30b1e4203ae3b2f6e2cd07#file-rxjs-firebase-demo-js-L45) from Chris Esplin.

```
Rx.Observable.fromEvent(ref, 'child_added').subscribe(function (snap) {
  console.log('child_added', snap.key);
});
```

So this creates an observable of `child_added` events, then subscribes to that observable, and print each event it gets.

Answer (score 2):

Once your Firebase object is initialized, simply attach a listener to the ref that you need to observe, and put it outside of your function. It should be something like:

```
// fb listener

// where to watch
const myRef = 'ressource/path'
const myDb = firebase.database()
const refToWatch = myDb.ref(myRef)

// the actual listener
refToWatch.on('child_changed', snapshot => {
  const s = snapshot.val()
  console.log(JSON.stringify(s))
})
```

See the [official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data) for more details